# Hot Deploying Class File in Tomcat

Tags: spring, grails, deployment, tomcat6

Forgetting about why I need to do this for a minute...

I need to deploy a handful of class files into an existing / running webapp.  I can't build and deploy the entire WAR for this.  I've copied the class files to the right place. Made sure the permissions on the files were right.  I've cleared Tomcat's work folder.  I've bounced Tomcat.  But it is still delivering results from the old class files.

If it matters, these class files relate to a Grails service class which is loaded as a singleton in the spring context.  I must be missing something but not sure what it is.

UPDATE: I tried extracting the existing WAR into a directory and replacing the class files in it, then repackaging it into a WAR and deploying the application.  Still no joy.  This is really perplexing.

Comment: Did you remove the WAR file? Depending on the configuration, Tomcat may redeploy your app from the WAR file on every restart.

Comment: Yes, I removed the WAR and it didn't make a difference. It was not overwriting the files anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what OS you are on but I had an issue similar to this where even after bouncing Tomcat the web app wouldn't die.  I was running my app on windows and had to check cmd `netstat -a` to see that the port was still in use after I tried to kill the app. Then checked under Component Services to kill the tomcat service. Application updated fine after restarting tomcat... I hope this helps

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Its linux, btw.

Comment: I looked up the process and did a kill -9 and then started tomcat back up.  Still not recognizing the new class.  At this point, I'm tempted to extract the WAR, put the class files in, zip the WAR back up and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of tomcat running on your machine? if so maybe some how one of those is still running a version of your application?